# Improving Date formatting JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am new to stackoverflow and recently started learning Javascript. May i know how can I improve the date format function. I have written in javascript (ES5/ES6). This code is just a part of exercise. Any help will be appreciated.

```
function formatDate() {
        let bookingDate = new Date();
        let dayNumber = bookingDate.getDay();
        let date = bookingDate.getDate();
        let month = bookingDate.getMonth();
        let year = bookingDate.getFullYear();

        return ` ${getWeekday(dayNumber)}, ${monthName(
      month
    )}  ${date},  ${year}`;

        function getWeekday(dayNumber) {
            let day = bookingDate.getDay();

            let DayName = [
                "Sunday",
                "Monday",
                "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday",
                "Thursday",
                "Friday",
                "Saturday"
            ];

            return DayName[dayNumber];
        }

        function monthName(month) {
            let monthNames = [
                "January",
                "February",
                "March",
                "April",
                "May",
                "June",
                "July",
                "August",
                "September",
                "October",
                "November",
                "December"
            ];

            return monthNames[month];
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this code works, then you should post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). If not, what isn't working?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment . This code is working and will post it on code review. Thanks for the suggestion